# Trigger for overlapping datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table given by code:

```
CREATE TABLE Event
(
    EventId INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT pk_Event PRIMARY KEY,
    ConferenceId INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ConferenceId) REFERENCES Conference(ConferenceId),
    RoomId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (RoomId) REFERENCES Room(RoomId),
    BeginDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT date_ck CHECK (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, beginDate, endDate) > 0 
                              AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, beginDate, endDate) <= 5)
);
```

Now I'm trying to create a trigger which will prevent from adding two events with overlapping time, now two events can happen at the same time. I have something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckTwoEventsForOverlapingTime
ON [dbo].Event  
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
    IF EXISTS(SELECT begindate, enddate
              FROM Event e
              WHERE e.conferenceId in (SELECT ConferenceId FROM inserted) 
                AND ((SELECT BeginDate FROM inserted) > BeginDate  
                     AND (SELECT BeginDate FROM inserted) <= EndDate) OR
                    ((SELECT EndDate FROM inserted) >= BeginDate  
                     AND (SELECT EndDate FROM inserted) < EndDate) OR
                    ((SELECT BeginDate FROM inserted) < BeginDate 
                     AND (SELECT EndDate FROM inserted) > EndDate)) 
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR('No two events can take place at the same time.', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK 
    END
GO
```

Sadly this doesn't want to work. If the event A start at 10AM at lasts till 1PM, when I try to add event B which start at 10AM but last till 2PM it doesn't throw an error. I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to check two sets. First there must not be any overlapping events in the `inserted` set. And then there must not be any overlapping events between the `inserted` and the untouched but remaining set, i.e. the set already in the table but not in `deleted`.

```
...
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM inserted i1
                       INNER JOIN inserted i2
                                  ON i1.conferenceid = i2.conferenceid
                                     AND i1.eventid <> i2.eventid
                                     AND i1.enddate > i2.begindate
                                     AND i1.begindate < i2.enddate)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM (SELECT *
                                  FROM event e1
                                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                           FROM deleted d1
                                                           WHERE d1.eventid = e1.eventid) e2
                          INNER JOIN inserted i2
                                     ON e2.conferenceid = i2.conferenceid
                                        AND e2.eventid <> i2.eventid
                                        AND e2.enddate > i2.begindate
                                        AND e2.begindate < i2.enddate))
BEGIN
  THROW 50000, 'No two events can take place at the same time.', 1;
END;
...
```

I also changed `RAISERROR` to a `THROW` as the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states:

> New applications should use [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  I think the logic is:

```
if exists (select 1
           from event e join
                inserted i
                on i.conferenceId = e.conferenceId and
                   i.begindate <= e.enddate and
                   i.enddate >= e.begindate
          )
begin 
    raiseerror('No two events can take place at the same time.', 16, 1);
    rollback; 
end;
```

The logic is that two events overlap when one begins (on or) before the second ends and first ends (on or) after the second begins.

The `rollback` is redundant -- the code never makes it there.

The exactly logic on `<=`/`<` and `>=`/`>` depends on how you define overlaps.  If one event is allowed to end exactly when the second begins, then use `<`/`>` instead.

Comment: It should be > and < instead of >= and <= (assuming end date is exclusive as described in OP).